# Include an executables into UWP final package

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, uwp, openssl

I'm writing an UWP Store app that calls other executables, such as OpenSSL and FFmpeg.exe. I successfully included those in a WPF app. However, with UWP, how to build them into the final package to upload to the Windows Store?

I'm thinking of these solutions:

1. Add the needed file (for example, FFmpeg.exe) to the project. Then chose the Build Action property to 'Content' and copy to Output Directory. But this option seems not possible with the whole folder with sub-folders and files in them (for example, OpenSSL portable folder).
2. Write a method to copy the file (FFmpeg.exe) into the Local Folder of UWP app when the program starts. 
   ...

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: With solution #2, it only works with local development machine. On the Windows Store app, when the user downloads the app, I would not want to app to look for the executable (or resource files) and copy to the LocalState Folder of the app. Thanks.

Comment: Since you're distributing `ffmpeg` make sure you are complying with the license.

Comment: @kangjmoon Have you tried to convert your WPF app to UWP app?

Answer (score 2):

You have to leverage the build powershell commands.

## 1 Step, Setting up

Go to your Solution Folder, and create a new Folder Called "MyExeFolder"
inside that folder put your desired .exe, like FFmpeg.exe

## 2 Step, Automating

Right click your entry Uwp Project and go to **Properties** and then go to **Build Events**

on your the Post Build event commands enter this :

xcopy /y /s "$(SolutionDir)MyExeFolder\FFmpeg.exe" "$(SolutionDir)\UWP\bin\x86\$(ConfigurationName)\AppX\"

If you are building for x64 too, then you also add the same command with x64 instead for x86 too, if you are building the win32 project along and grouping it under the same solution, you have to define the appropriate bin folder.

## 3 Step Executing

In order to launch win32 apps from uwp you will have to use an a capability called **runFullTrust**, it is hard to list all the xml modifications you will have to do to the app manifest to enable such feature but once you figure it out, you will have to add this to the Extension node:

```
<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" 
Executable="FFmpeg.exe" />
```

[here is more info on how to set up the manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion)

Once you pull all this off you can just launch your win32 part from anywhere on your uwp app by :

```
try  {             
                await Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
              //failed to Launch
            }
```

As for Further reading, i suggest you visit [stefan wicks](https://stefanwick.com/2017/06/24/uwp-app-with-systray-extension/) blog as he has a great wealth of samples and tuts on how to overcome uwp limitations by using .Net native extensibility.